# How to hide/remove the title bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-titlebar

In my code I write:

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I've written all of it before the `setContentView()` call is made but it doesn't work.

I've already used the theme in android studio to remove the title bar and set the app to fullscreen but nothing changed.

**How can I remove or hide the title bar that shows by default, when developing an android app?**

Comment: You might want to do this in the xml file for main activity.

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you .@Twing90

Answer (score 6):

## To inherit from a predefined style definition

**1. Create a new style definition in your `styles.xml` file and make it a child of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.**

```
For example:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**2. Add the new style definition to your application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file**

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

---

## To specify the individual properties

Add the following properties to a new or existing style definition in the `styles.xml` file and ensure the style definition has been referenced in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, as above:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code in onCreate() method before setContentView(...)

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

The getSupportActionBar() method is used to retrieve the instance of ActionBar class. Calling the hide() method of ActionBar class hides the title bar.

Answer (score 3):

go to values and select styles.xml
change AppTheme to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: it's work for the top bar who show the time, but I need to hide the bar who show the project name. Is it possible??

Comment: you can create view in the top and using show and Gone view property